# Difference between positive and negative Mitzvos when it comes to Chinuch

Tags: halacha, children-parenting, chinuch-education, mishnah-berurah

The Mishnah Berurah (343:3) writes that when it comes to positive Mitzvos, Chinuch begins from when the child is able to understand the purpose of that specific Mitzvah, but when it comes to negative Mitzvos, Chinuch begins as soon as he understands what it means when he is told that something is forbidden - even if he doesn’t understand the reason for the prohibition.

The question is: why is there a difference in this case between positive and negative Mitzvos?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because in both instances they serve a different purpose.

In the case of the asei (the positive commandment) that is something that a child will learn to perform properly with all its details as they continue to grow up and therefore there has to be a degree of intellect there to understand the mechanics of the mitzvah.

Refer to the Gemara in [Succah 42a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sukkah.42a.10?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> תָּנוּ רַבָּנַן: קָטָן הַיּוֹדֵעַ לְנַעְנֵעַ — חַיָּיב בְּלוּלָב, לְהִתְעַטֵּף — חַיָּיב בְּצִיצִית, לִשְׁמוֹר תְּפִילִּין — אָבִיו לוֹקֵחַ לוֹ תְּפִילִּין, יוֹדֵעַ לְדַבֵּר — אָבִיו מְלַמְּדוֹ תּוֹרָה וּקְרִיאַת שְׁמַע
>
> Our Rabbis taught: A minor who knows how to wave a lulav is obligated in (the mitzvah) of lulav, (how) to wrap himself is obligated in tzitzis, (how) to preserve (the sanctity) of tefillin – his father is obligated to buy him tefillin, if he knows how to speak his father should teach him Torah and Shema.

So once there is a degree of understanding behind the action, the child can be carefully trained to perform the act more readily, harnessing the excitement etc for the mitzvah.

Conversely, with the lo saasei (negative commandment) it is about creating a habit. Namely, to inculcate from the get-go a simple awareness that we don't do certain actions. As the adage goes (See [Midrash Shmuel on Pirkei Avos 1:14](https://www.sefaria.org/Midrash_Shmuel_on_Avot.1.14.7?vhe=Midrash_Shmuel,_Warsaw,_1876&lang=bi) who quotes ר"י ן' שושן ז"ל):

> ההרגל על כל דבר שלטון
>
> The habit of something holds sway

Creating good habits early on will hopefully withstand the test of time. For example, the Gemara in [Eiruvin 40b](https://www.sefaria.org/Eruvin.40b.13?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) speaks about making kiddush in shul on Yom Kippur night. It notes that one cannot recite kiddush on a cup of wine without tasting it immediately after the bracha has been said. In fact [Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Eruvin.40b.15?lang=bi&p2=Rashi_on_Eruvin.40b.15.1&lang2=bi) adds that to do so is a גנאי, a disgrace. Due to the fact that it is a fast day we obviously would not be able to drink from the cup. Thus, the Gemara suggests offering it to a minor to drink, thereby allowing for the potential to say it. However, the Gemara concludes:

> דילמא אתי למסרך
>
> Perhaps he (the child) might become used to it.

As [Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Eruvin.40b.15?lang=bi&p2=Rashi_on_Eruvin.40b.15.3&lang2=bi&w2=all&lang3=en) explains, should the child drink the wine, he might become acclimatised to such a practise even after he becomes Bar Mitzvah. Therefore, we see from this Gemara that anything that might come to create a negative inclination in the child must be avoided.

Comment: Sorry for breaking stack exchange rules with a thank you comment, but wow, amazing answer Dov

Comment: @RabbiKaii - thank you I really appreciate that!

Comment: we all appreciate you and this answer! Now excuse me while I go see if my kids are awake so I can teach them to shake a lulav

Comment: Lol hatzlocho! :-)

Comment: When Tisha bav falls on a Sunday the wine from havdala is given to a child to drink. Is that considered a bad habit?

Comment: Tisha B'Av is not as strict as Yom Kippur in this regard i.e. there's no chiyuv kareis